# Why is Vue giving error while loading image

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am getting this error when I am trying to load image in vue using vuetify.

Error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined"`

The component:

```
<v-file-input
          accept="image/*"
          label="File input"
          @change="uploadData($event)"
        ></v-file-input>
```

The method:

```
 methods: {
    uploadData(event) {
      let file = event.target.files[0];
      console.log(file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@change` has `files` array as parameter by default, no need to specify the `$event` parameter :

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-file-input
      accept="image/*"
      label="File input"
       @change="uploadData"       
    ></v-file-input>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
   methods: {
    uploadData(files) {
   console.log(files)
    }
}
})
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/bGedRWK)**